# Small issue with boxes in HTML5 and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a minor issue with boxes around some text areas of my website. If you look at my picture (right boxes), the right border is not long enough and the bottom border is not at the same height as the left one... but I would like!

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```css
.bloc50 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(231, 7, 7);
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc50">
  <h3>Détails:</h3>
  <h4>Date naissance:</h4>
  <p>6 mai 19</p>
  <h4>Lieu naissance:</h4>
  <p>Grand Mère</p>
  <h4>Date décès:</h4>
  <p>N/A</p>
  <h4>Lieu décès:</h4>
  <p>N/A</p>
</div>
<div class="bloc50">
  <h3>Frères & soeurs:</h3>
  <p><a href="pierrel.html">Pierre Lefebvre</a></p>
  <p><a href="patrickl.html">Patrick Lefebvre</a></p>
</div>
```

I tried to put a div before those 2 div but didn't like the result.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/max_max/nkm5w4Lt/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to place all of these `.bloc50` div elements within a parent container ( I used a DIV here ) & apply some basic `flexbox` styles

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  border:1px solid black
  
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-content:flex-start;
}

.wrapper .bloc50{
  width:50%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(231, 7, 7);
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="bloc50">
    <h3>Détails:</h3>
    <h4>Date naissance:</h4>
    <p>6 mai 19</p>
    <h4>Lieu naissance:</h4>
    <p>Grand Mère</p>
    <h4>Date décès:</h4>
    <p>N/A</p>
    <h4>Lieu décès:</h4>
    <p>N/A</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bloc50">
    <h3>Frères & soeurs:</h3>
    <p><a href="pierrel.html">Pierre Lefebvre</a></p> 
    <p><a href="patrickl.html">Patrick Lefebvre</a></p> 
  </div>

  <div class="bloc50">
    <h3>Détails:</h3>
    <h4>Date naissance:</h4>
    <p>6 mai 19</p>
    <h4>Lieu naissance:</h4>
    <p>Grand Mère</p>
    <h4>Date décès:</h4>
    <p>N/A</p>
    <h4>Lieu décès:</h4>
    <p>N/A</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bloc50">
    <h3>Frères & soeurs:</h3>
    <p><a href="pierrel.html">Pierre Lefebvre</a></p> 
    <p><a href="patrickl.html">Patrick Lefebvre</a></p> 
  </div>
</div>
```